# Why isn't my Laravel Nova error reporting to Sentry

Tags: laravel, error-handling, sentry, laravel-nova

In my app `Handler.php` I have this as per the Sentry docs

```php
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
            app('sentry')->captureException($e);
        }
    });
}
```

and in my `NovaServiceProvider.php` I have as per the Nova docs.

```php
public function register()
    {
        Nova::report(function ($exception) {
            if (app()->bound('sentry')) {
                app('sentry')->captureException($exception);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, none of my errors from Nova are being passed to Sentry. Other errors are being passed just fine.

Using Nova 3.32.0 and Sentry 2.12

Comment: What kind of exceptions are being thrown in Nova and are you not seeing in Sentry? I’m expecting Nova filters out some exceptions from being reported. I would honestly think the first snippet is het only one you’d need and there should be no need for a Nova specific handler, but I’d be happy to dig into a little, your code seems like it would work just fine.

Comment: Internal server error when trying to save a resource that uses Nova Flexible Content package. Can't replicate locally either which doesn't help matters, and I'm also running on Vapor.

Comment: Sorry I was looking for a little more specific if you got it, is the error showing up in the Vapor logs and can you get a little more info from that?

Comment: yeah, nothing more specific than that sadly and nothing appearing in Vapor logs either making it incredibly tough to trace.